# connected nilpotent subgroup of Isom(R^n)

Tags: lie-groups, abelian-groups

Is it true that every connected nilpotent Lie subgroup of Isom(R^n), the isometry group of R^n, is actually abelian?

Any reference on it?

Comment: Yes, this is true. Hint: First consider connected nilpotent subgroups of the orthogonal group.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I know that any connected nilpotent Lie subgroup of O(n) is a torus since it is compact.

Comment: OK. I figure it out.

Comment: Good job. Now you can even write a solution in order to take this question from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1):

This result is well known, and it is worth, I think, to look into a book on geometry for a detailed proof and additional background. One possible reference is the book on [Three-Dimensional Geometry and Topology, Volume 1](https://books.google.at/books?id=5irlDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=a+connected+nilpotent+subgroup+of+Isom(R%5En)+is+abelian&source=bl&ots=EIi5x26Fr0&sig=7U3fUpldnsPVhX7JqkLRAgW_ZZc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG2PK45I3SAhXsC5oKHfXhAAgQ6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=a%20connected%20nilpotent%20subgroup%20of%20Isom(R%5En)%20is%20abelian&f=false) by Thurston,
namely  Corollary $4.1.13$ and its proof. There it says "*to  complete the proof we must show that any connected, closed nilpotent subgroup $N\subseteq Isom(E^n)$ is abelian.*" The proof given there uses induction, and of course a result on subgroups of $O(n)$, and is certainly worth reading.